# If I convert a sequence to an array and treat it as a sequence, do I get O(1) on length?

Tags: arrays, f#, seq

I was wondering whether I would get special treatment when a sequence is converted to an array and then henceforth treated as a sequence again.

```
let sq = seq { for i in 0 .. 10 do yield i }
let arr = Seq.toArray sq
let len = Array.length arr      // O(1)
let sq2 = arr |> Seq.ofArray

// from converted seq
let len2 = Seq.length sq2       // O(n)???

// or direct:
let len2 = Seq.length arr       // O(n)???
```

On the same token, is F# smart enough with `Seq.toArray arr` to simply create a copy of the array, to leave it alone (not create a copy), or would it iterate over each item using the enumerator?

Put in another way, do sequence in F# *remember* somehow that their internal structure is an array?

I am asking this since on expensive sequences, you may need the length multiple times, and evaluating it once would be beneficial. I can either create a specific sequence type that remembers the length, or I could use the magic that's already there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the sequence is actually an array type then it will simply be cast back to an array to determine the array within `Seq.length`.  You can see this in in the implementation of the `length` function [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L1106):

```
[<CompiledName("Length")>]
let length (source : seq<'T>)    = 
    checkNonNull "source" source
    match source with 
    | :? ('T[]) as a -> a.Length
    | :? ('T list) as a -> a.Length
    | :? ICollection<'T> as a -> a.Count
    | _ -> 
        use e = source.GetEnumerator() 
        let mutable state = 0 
        while e.MoveNext() do
            state <-  state + 1;
        state
```

You can see this behaviour if you put it in FSI:

```
let arr = [|1..40000000|];;
```

Using `Array.length`:

> ```
> Array.length arr;;
> Real: 00:00:00.000, CPU: 00:00:00.015, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
> val it : int = 40000000
> ```

Using `Seq.length`:

> ```
> Seq.length arr;;
> Real: 00:00:00.000, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
> val it : int = 40000000
> ```

---

If you use `Seq.ofArray` you are specifically hiding the underlying type information, creating a new enumerator that steps through the array element by element.

This can be a useful behaviour because it prevents a consumer of your API from sneakily casting `seq<'T>` back to `'T[]` and consequently allowing said consumer to mutate something that you, the API designer, expected to be exposing an immutable view of.

The downside of this information hiding is that you can't cast back to array so the enumeration becomes significantly slower:

> ```
> Seq.length <| Seq.ofArray arr;;
> Real: 00:00:00.148, CPU: 00:00:00.140, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
> val it : int = 40000000
> ```

`Seq.ofArray` uses the [`mkSeq` function](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L588) which just creates an anonymous `IEnumerable` from an `ArrayEnumerator`:

```
let mkSeq f = 
    { new IEnumerable<'U> with 
          member x.GetEnumerator() = f()
      interface IEnumerable with 
          member x.GetEnumerator() = (f() :> IEnumerator) }
```

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer, very helpful. Though even with information hiding, the `mkSeq`, if input is an array, could have been optimized to retrieve length in `O(1)`, I don't see how that would be problematic (other than that it requires some coding), as it is of no influence to mutability.

Comment: @Abel Yes, I guess it's a possible optimisation although not completely trivial as it requires some extra type information to know that the length is indeed already defined.  The easiest way would probably be via `IReadOnlyCollection<'T>` although this interface hasn't been widely (or perhaps at all) adopted in FSharp.Core yet so perhaps in the future...

Comment: Huh.. I really assumed that `Seq.ofArray` was just a named upcast, i.e. `let inline ofArray (arr:'a[]) : seq<'a> = upcast arr`. I don't see the value of the actual implementation given the negative performance implications of the type-erasure. :-/

Comment: @ildjarn It's obviously no problem for immutable types but if you can cast an immutable API to a mutable one, you have big big problems.  Compare to `Seq.ofList` (https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L1186) which can just upcast because Lists are immutable.

Answer (score 2):

`Seq.ofArray` returns an [ArrayEnumerator](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L329) which only implements `IEnumerator<T>` so calling `Seq.length` on it will require enumerating the entire sequence to get the length.

Calling [`Seq.length`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L1124) on an array directly will use the underlying `Length` property since it does a dynamic type check for array types, list and instances of `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: Hmm, how would I get that behavior? I just tried it in FSI and on `for i in 0 .. 100000000 do Seq.length sq |> ignore;;` I get 18 secs, on `for i in 0 .. 100000000 do Array.length arr |> ignore;;` I get 52msecs, where `let sq = Seq.ofArray arr` and `arr` is an `array<int>` of size 20. _What am I overlooking here?_

Comment: @Abel - `Seq.ofArray` returns an `ArrayEnumerator` which only implements `IEnumerable<T>` so that will iterate over the inner array to get the length. Calling `Seq.length` on an array directly will use the `.Length` property on the array.

Comment: @Abel - Perhaps `Seq.length` should be updated to check for `IReadOnlyCollection` which `ArrayEnumerator<T>` would be able to implement.

Comment: So that essentially means that the correct answer is the inverse of your answer... It is _not_ keeping the info that it was created from an array. Which makes me wonder, is it possible to create a sequence `Seq<'T>` that does remember it has an array underneath?

Comment: @Abel - See update. The original answer only contained the behaviour of `Seq.length arr`.